# Remove initial progress bar display

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic2, ionic3

Can you tell me how to remove the initial display value of the progress bar where It shows even though the value is `0`? It seems CSS issue.But no luck to solve it yet.

[image]

**Runtime CSS:**

[image]

**.scss**

```
 .progress-outer {
            width: 96%;
            margin: 10px 2%;
            padding: 3px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }
        .progress-inner {

            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            background-color: map-get($colors, primary);
        }
```

**.html**

```
 <progress-bar [progress]="loadProgress"></progress-bar>
```

**.ts**

```
loadProgress: string = '';
```

I have used [**this article**](https://www.joshmorony.com/build-a-simple-progress-bar-component-in-ionic-2/) to create the component.

Comment: Putting a simple `*ngIf` doesn't solve this? `<progress-bar [progress]="loadProgress" *ngIf="loadProgress > 0"></progress-bar>`.

Comment: `loadProgress` is a `string` variable no? @developer033

Comment: I don't know, is it? :) Where does it come from?

Comment: Here `<div class="progress-inner" [style.width]="progress + '%'">`. You can see more about this if you see the mentioned article above.@developer033

Comment: Nah, I meant that you're calling it from another component, right? So, how did you define the `loadProgress` variable?

Comment: Yes.It calculates automatically.I have defined it like this: `loadProgress: string = '';` @developer033

Comment: So, how is it *calculating automatically* with a `string` *variable*?

Comment: Like this :D `this.loadProgress = _.round((((questionNumber - 1) / this.numberOfSections) * 100), 1).toString();` @developer033

Comment: I'd prefer to store it as number and remove this `toString()`, so you can use `loadProgress > 0` in template.

Comment: Your solution will completely remove the progress bar when it doesn't have a value no.But I need to show empty one too. @developer033

Answer (score 0):

If the progress-bar is your own custom component, then have the *ngIf for the progress-inner div or you could even use [hidden] on that when progress is zero.

If its not your own custom component you might need to manipulate the inner div inside your .ts file to hide it, by using the ElementRef.

Comment: Good suggestion.I'll try that and will let you know.The component is mine.